# How to use React Router inside <select> tag ?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How is it possible or is there any alternative to use `React Router v4` - more concretely `<Link>` inside `<select>` tag.

Assumably, code looks like this

```
<div className="col-lg-4">
    <select id="categories" onChange={handleCategories} className="form-control">
        {
            this.state.temp.map((i, index) => <option key={index}>{i}</option>)
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

How can I use `Link` in order to change `pathname` ?

I tried this, throws no errors, but doesn't change `pathname`

```
this.state.temp.map((i, index) => <option key={index}><Link to = "/whatever">{i}</Link></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your `handleCategories`method

```
handleCategories = ({ target } => {
 this.props.history.push(`/foo/${target.value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.props.history.push changes url but does not load/render the page